# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS loads noticeably slower compare with 14.04

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, upgrade, desktop-environments

After uprading Ubuntu to 16.04 LTS I noticed that Ubuntu loads noticeably slower compare with 14.04. This mean it takes more time to load login screen after PC power on, and much more interval between entering password and populating Ubuntu desktop. Is there way to fix this issue?

EDIT: added `systemd-analyze blame` output.

```
         14.737s networking.service
         13.727s apport.service
         13.666s speech-dispatcher.service
         11.593s dev-sda3.device
          9.058s iio-sensor-proxy.service
          9.055s rsyslog.service
          9.029s systemd-user-sessions.service
          8.979s thermald.service
          8.059s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          7.600s apparmor.service
          7.314s accounts-daemon.service
          4.996s grub-common.service
          4.665s irqbalance.service
          4.638s ondemand.service
          4.155s console-setup.service
          3.771s lightdm.service
          3.414s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
          2.914s NetworkManager.service
          2.017s systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
          1.760s systemd-udevd.service
          1.479s resolvconf.service
          1.451s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
          1.442s ModemManager.service
lines 1-23...skipping...
         14.737s networking.service
         13.727s apport.service
         13.666s speech-dispatcher.service
         11.593s dev-sda3.device
          9.058s iio-sensor-proxy.service
          9.055s rsyslog.service
          9.029s systemd-user-sessions.service
          8.979s thermald.service
          8.059s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          7.600s apparmor.service
          7.314s accounts-daemon.service
          4.996s grub-common.service
          4.665s irqbalance.service
          4.638s ondemand.service
          4.155s console-setup.service
          3.771s lightdm.service
          3.414s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
          2.914s NetworkManager.service
          2.017s systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
          1.760s systemd-udevd.service
          1.479s resolvconf.service
          1.451s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
          1.442s ModemManager.service
          1.208s plymouth-start.service
          1.035s systemd-journald.service
          1.000s systemd-modules-load.service
           918ms keyboard-setup.service
           905ms gpu-manager.service
           696ms upower.service
           688ms udisks2.service
           678ms systemd-update-utmp.service
           583ms dev-disk-by\x2duuid-b6b1a8eb\x2d15a0\x2d4f95\x2da7d4\x2df5291de0b7a8.swap
           541ms avahi-daemon.service
           502ms dev-mqueue.mount
           422ms ufw.service
           377ms polkitd.service
           332ms colord.service
           326ms kmod-static-nodes.service
```

Comment: Run `systemd-analyze blame` and add it to your question

Comment: So the most time consuming is first 4 services. What is wrong with 16.04 LTS? Seems its quite common issue with 16.04 LTS.